# Shortcut keys for Javascript game GUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hotkeys

I've been making a simple javascript based OOP text game that uses string replacement and variable adjustments tied to button .onclick events. I've been asked to add hotkeys for easier access, and I've been struggling with how to do it.

First I tried using the JSQuery hotkeys script and the .bind command, but that seemed like it would be very time consuming as I'd have to recode every .onclick as a hotkey, and even with unbind, it was firing off every event tied to the key on the script.

I feel like the best way to do would be if I could code the keys to the gui, i.e. if when you pressed "1", it activated the .onclick of button 1, that way the hotkey would be static (except when the button is disabled), but I've no idea how to do that. I've just been using html buttons, (i.e. input type="button" value="" disabled="disabled" id="button1"), I suspect I'd need something more sophisticated?

Thanks in advance for any help, google has been useless.

[EDIT - General description of code]

The way the game works is very simple, via the calling of functions as new events with different text/buttons (and different onclick events tied to those buttons). As an example, the start screen code is:

```
function startScreen() {
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#text').html("Game title and info");
$('#button1').val("Start Game");
$('#button1').attr("disabled", false);
$("#button1").one("click", function () {
textClear();
buttonClear();
nameScreen();
});

$("#button2").val("Load Game");
$('#button2').attr("disabled", false);
$("#button2").one("click", function () {
textClear();
buttonClear();  
loadData();
});

$("#button6").val("Settings");
$('#button6').attr("disabled", false);
$("#button6").one("click", function () {
textClear();
buttonClear();
settingsScreen();   
});
});
}
```

Since the code executed by button one changes between functions, what the hotkey does as well, which was my problem with using the JQuery library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a key is pressed then the event `onkeypress` is fired. This event provides some values like:

- `keyCode`
- `charCode`
- `which`

So you could do something like:

```
window.onkeypress = function (event) {
    // the keyCode value for the key 1 is 49, for the key 2 is 50
    if (event.keyCode == 49) {
        // execute the same code as clicking the button 1
        console.log("The key 1 was pressed.");
    } else if (event.keyCode == 50) {
        // execute the same code as clicking the button 2
        console.log("The key 2 was pressed.");
    }
};
```

Now, when a user visits your website he could press the keys 1 or 2 on the keyboard and fire the same logic as clicking the buttons "1" and "2" (being something like `<input id="button1">`) with the left mouse taste.

If you have really a lot of hotkeys then this would be also tedious to type, but without knowing your code I can hardly give you a complete solution. I hope my answer can give you some idea how to proceed further.

EDIT:

Further reading on the topic:
http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html